# How to control processes and threads in hybrid OpenMP/MPI job

Tags: openmp, gnu, openmpi

I'm trying to control the distribution of MPI processes and their threads. In a 4-core system (cores 0, 1, 2 and 3) with GNU compilers and OpenMPI, submitting a 2x2 job (*export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 && mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings exec*) will assign the 2 MPI processes to 0 and 1 [I'm unsure how the threads are spread on the other cores -as this info is not reported- so my assumption is that they are pinned to cores 2 & 3 respectively].

The problems start when I try to force the MPI processes into running on cores 0 and 2. I have tried several combinations. The first one (*export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 && export OMP_PLACES=cores && export OMP_PROC_BIND=close && mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings exec*) results in the same distribution. The second submits the job as (*export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 && export OMP_PLACES="{0,2}" && export OMP_PROC_BIND=close && mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings exec*) but this leads to the error message:

```
libgomp: None of the places contain usable logical CPUs

libgomp: Invalid value for environment variable OMP_PLACES
```

I wasn't expecting this error and was wondering why this is happening.
Thanks.

Comment: I find the explicit `PLACES` specification with braces pretty inscrutable. Your first strategy looks good. What's the problem with it?

Comment: I have edited the post a bit. Hopefully, it's now clearer what works and what is producing an error (I just don't understand what the message "None of the places contain usable logical CPUS" mean and why it's happening).

Comment: Your OMP setting are irrelevant once MPI has placed the processes. Use `numactl` or `hwloc` or another tool to place the MPI processes correctly. You can do that with a non-OMP code for starters.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but I thought that OpenMPI uses hwloc internally. Could you provide a quick example of what you're suggesting to do? Thanks.